# Command result capture into variable is not working

Tags: file, variables, batch-file, text, set

I have a complicated batch script involving multiple BCP commands that load SQL server with flat file data.  I am using a branch statement that logs the result of the command into a log file.  This is all working fine.

The result is also logged in an SQL table as a success or failure.  What I am trying to do is, upon failure, insert the contents of the log file into the SQL log table using what I thought was a simple redirect. It isn't working.

Here is what I am doing in a batch file in a Win Server 2012 environment:

```
BCP (the parameters here don't matter) >> %LogFile% (
    MOVE %FileName% to Archive/%FileName%
    sqlcmd -E -Q "EXEC spImportLog 'SUCCESS', %FileName%, ''
) || (
   SET /p LogText=<%LogFile%
   sqlcmd -E -Q "EXEC spImportLog 'FAILED', %FileName%, %LogText%
)
```

This code executes without error.  The true part of the statement works fine.
The false part executes fine but I end up with empty string instead of
the contents of %LogText%.

When I run this from a command prompt, the SET looks like this:

SET /p LogText<0Log_2016_9_23.log

The %LogFile% is a variable because it is dynamically named at run time based on today's date.  I don't know where the 0 after the less than sign is coming from, or if it is the source of my problem.  Any ideas?

Comment: I guess there is `&&` missing at the end of the `BCP` command line right before the last `(`... Is `BCP` a batch file? if so precede it with `call`. For `LogText` you need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) as you are modifying *and* reading that variable within the same block of code...

Comment: Yes there is a && just before the (.  I have edited my original code with BCP (my parameters) >> %LogFile% && ( true statement) || (SET /p LogText=<%LogFile%  sqlcmd -E -Q "EXEC spImportLog 'FAILED',%FileName%,!LogText! )

Comment: delayed expansion is set at the beginning of the batch file and stopping it at the end.  It is still not working.

Comment: Note that `SET /p LogText=<%LogFile%` only assigns the *first* line of text to the variable; you might be expecting something else...?

Answer (score 0):

YADXP.

```
   SET /p LogText=<%LogFile%
   setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
   sqlcmd -E -Q "EXEC spImportLog 'FAILED', %FileName%, !LogText!
   endlocal
```

should work. See the billion or so SO entries about "delayed expansion"

---

As I said, `set /p var=<filename` will set the variable from the **first** line of the file. Since the file accumulates values and is initially sset to contain just one line (AAUI) 'None' then *that* is the value that will be read from the file.

Try

```
   for /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a in ("%LogFile%") do set "logtext=%%a"
   setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
   sqlcmd -E -Q "EXEC spImportLog 'FAILED', %FileName%, !LogText!
   endlocal
```

which should read every line of `%logfile%` and assign to `logtest` the value (of each line) in turn, so that when the `for` terminates, `logtext` will have the value of the **last** line of the file.

Comment: I have tried the above.  So far it isn't working.  What I tried is setting the delayed expansion at the beginning of the batch and ending it at the end after all of the BCP commands have run.  That didn't work.  No error, just the same result.  I will try wrapping it around the sqlcmd statement as the answer displays to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Surrounding the sqlcmd statement didn't work either.  To elaborate further, I initialize the LogText variable with 'None' at the beginning of my batch.  'None' is what gets insterted into my log table, rather than the result of the SET /p LogText=<%LogFile% statement.  Hope that helps . . .

Comment: Just verified by running three of the bcp statements in a row.  The state of LogFile is not changing.  It remains 'None'.

Comment: So `logfile` always contains just `None` ? You are aware that `>>` appends to the file, are you not? Consequently, if `BCP` generates output, that output will be appended to the initial `None`. `set /p` will read just the first line. Do you want to read the last line - but as you say, `logfile` is not changing.

Comment: Oops, I meant that the state of the variable %LogText% doesn't change.  The log file appends correctly with the BCP output.  The problem I am trying to solve is storing the contents of %LogFile% in the variable %LogText% and it isn't working.  The state of %LogText% never changes from its' initial value of 'None'.  Also, as a test, I tried to SET the value of %LogText% using a hard-coded name instead of the variable name.  It also doesn't work.  ie..  SET /p LogText=Log_2016_09_23.log

Comment: I am open to trying something else beside this SET statement.  All I am trying to do is capture the result of BCP and storing in in a variable.  I needn't use a file if there is a way without it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, thanks for the posts.  It doesn't sound like what I want to do is possible.  At least not the way I am trying to do it.  What I wanted is to store the entire contents of %LogFile% in a variable as a textstream, and then insert that text stream into a varchar column in SQL server.  In retrospect, I wasn't clear enough in my initial post exactly the problem I was trying to solve.  I know I can store the command results (multiple lines) in a temporary table in SQL Server.  It is just that it requires using xp_cmdshell, which I was hoping to avoid.